# <f:link.action> generation in standaloneview adds two underscores (__)

Tags: typo3, extbase

I'm creating a simple user registration. For that i sent a confirmation mail with hash via the `standaloneView` and used `f:link.action` to create the link. It looks as follows.

```
<f:link.action pluginName="pi1" controller="MyController" action="myAction" arguments="{token: '{token}'}" absolute="true" noCache="true" noCacheHash="true">Confirm</f:link.action>
```

The created link looks like:

> http://www.example.com/mySite/?no_cache=1&tx__pi1%5Btoken%5D=16d5056f209b72422bffa1e6973582190243446f&tx__pi1%5Baction%5D=myAction&tx__pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=myController

My second try was:

```
<f:link.action pluginName="extKey_pi1" controller="MyController" action="myAction" arguments="{token: '{token}'}" absolute="true" noCache="true" noCacheHash="true">Confirm</f:link.action>
```

The created link looks like:

> http://www.example.com/mySite/?no_cache=1&tx__extKey_pi1%5Btoken%5D=16d5056f209b72422bffa1e6973582190243446f&tx__extKey_pi1%5Baction%5D=myAction&tx__extKey_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=myController

Here 2 underscores ( `__` ) halve been added.

How can i solve this? I can setup an href manually but that isn't very neat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't create a link within the current extension, you have to provide the `extensionName` as a parameter as well. Note that you have to pass the name of the extension without underscores.

```
<f:link.action
    extensionName="extKey"
    pluginName="pi1"
    controller="MyController"
    action="myAction"
    arguments="{token: '{token}'}"
    absolute="true"
    noCache="true"
    noCacheHash="true"
>
    Confirm
</f:link.action>
```